# Family of holomorphic functions in unit disk with all derivatives bounded by $n!$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of holomorphic functions in the unit disk satisfying $|f^{(n)}| \leq n!$ for all $n \geq 0$. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family.

Is it not enough to fix a compact region $K$ in the unit disk and immediately infer that the family is equicontinuous on the basis that the functions have bounded (first) derivatives? This is using the characterization of normal families of holomorphic functions as being equicontinuous on all compact subsets and all sets $\{f(z)\}$ being relatively compact (which is obvious).

Is there more to this question?

Comment: Are you familiar with Montel's theorem?

Comment: Yes. I believe it states that uniformly bounded families (on compact subsets of the region) are normal? I suppose that gives another immediate proof of this result. Or is there more to this question?

Comment: If you know Montel's theorem this questions seems silly to me.  Maybe they expected an application of Arzela Ascoli.

Comment: Yeah, it felt a little silly to me. I figured there must be something I'm overlooking since the rest of the problems on my assignment haven't been so trivial. But I don't happen to know the source of the question, so it might just be a question that tries to motivate Montel's theorem (or related results).